# Typescript copy properties of an object using for..in

Tags: typescript, extract

I'm trying to copy the properties of an object using for..in but I got the error:

Type 'Greeter[Extract]' is not assignable to type 'this[Extract]'.

Any ideas how to solve this?

```
class Greeter {
a: string;
b: string;
c: string;
// etc

constructor(cloned: Greeter) {

    for (const i in this) {
        if (cloned.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            this[i] = cloned[i];
        }
    }
}
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Greeter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20c%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20etc%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(cloned%3A%20Greeter)%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20(const%20i%20in%20this)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(cloned.hasOwnProperty(i))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this%5Bi%5D%20%3D%20cloned%5Bi%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A) is the sample in the typescript playground.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the type of `this` is not `Greeter` it's the [polymorphic `this` type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/4910). An unfortunate consequence is that the `i` in your for loop i typed as `keyof this` while `Greeting` can be indexed using a `keyof Greeting`. These may seem like the same thing, but if you consider that `Greeting` can be derived, `keyof this` could potentially contain a lot more members. A similar discussion applies to the value of the indexing operation.

The compiler is not wrong, `this` may have more keys than `Greeter` so this is not 100% safe.

The simplest solution is to use a type assertion to change the type of `this`:

```
class Greeter {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: string;
    // etc

    constructor(cloned: Greeter) {
        for (const i in this as Greeter) {
            if (cloned.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                this[i] = cloned[i]
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Or you can iterate over the `cloned` object:

```
class Greeter {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: string;
    // etc

    constructor(cloned: Greeter) {
        for (const i in cloned) {
            if (cloned.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                this[i] = cloned[i]
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know anything about that topic, i'll work through it.
It seems that also the following seems to work...

      for (const i in this) {
        if (i in cert) {
          this[i] = cert[i.toString()];
        }
      }

Comment: @user2010955 Depends on your compiler settings with `noImplictAny`,  `cert[i.toString()]` will not work. Also your solution has a runtime impact, type assertions are free as far as runtime costs are concerned :)